# How to modify object from updates and remove old keys?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a multiplayer game and I have an object in javascript, with a number of keys and values.

This object is called players, for holding information about each player that is connected to the game server.

`name` is the key of the object, and then the value of the object is a `Player` object which holds information such as `x`, `y`, `level`, etc.

Constantly I am sending a request to the server to get updated information about the players.

Because this is happening very often, I don't want the `players` object to be reset every time (`players = {}`), so instead, I am updating the object with any **new** information.

At the moment I am checking `if name in players`, and if so, I update the object like this:

```
players[name].x = x;
players[name].y = y;
// etc.
```

Otherwise, I simply create a new `Player` object, with the information and add it to the `players` object. (If a new player connected for instance)

The problem is, if a player that is already in `players` is no longer in the updated information from the server (i.e the player disconnected), how do I go about removing them from the object.

Is it necessary to loop trough `players`, and if the player is no longer in the updated information, remove it from the object, or is there any simpler way of doing this?

If there is no other way, is it a better approach to just reset the dictionary and add the data? It feels like that isn't the best way to do something simple like this.

Here is my code so far:

```
var newplayers = new info from server;

for(var i=0; i<newplayers.length; i++)
{
    var pl = newplayers[i];

    var name = pl.name;

    var x = pl.x;
    var y = pl.y;
    // etc.

    if(name in players)
    {
        players[name].x = x;
        players[name].y = y;
        // etc.
    } else
        newplayer = new Player();
        newplayer.x = x;
        newplayer.y = y;
        // etc.
        players[name] = newplayer;
    }
}

// What if the player is no longer in the updated info, but still in players?
```

All help appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that dictionaries are called objects in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I thought you could use both names. I'll update the question.

Comment: As you are updating the old players info with new players, and adding the new players into old players, then we can simply set `players = newplayers` I don't see a need for a for-loop.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but actually newplayers has a different format than players, so I cannot do it that way. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a choice between removing outdated data from your `players` dictionary or rebuild it from scratch every time?

I think the answer depends a lot on how much data you have. If you have at most 20 players, it probably doesn't matter too much. If you have 1 million players it's different.

If you want to be sure, the best thing to do would be to measure it. Try both solutions with the biggest number of players you want to be able to handle and see what the impact on performance is.

Or just go with the simplest implementation and see if it's good enough for your purpose. No point in optimising before you need it.

Personally I'd just loop through `players` to remove the outdated data. If the performance is not good enough, then I'd optimise.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! There might be up to a hundred players at once, but it'd probably be fine.